# docker run command returns nothing

Tags: python, bash, amazon-web-services, docker, containers

I've built the image successfully, but when I run `docker run <xxxx:latest>` it returns nothing.

I also have a bash script that contains AWS crendential (because a Python script within the container requires credential to log into AWS to perform something), when I tried to run that script it also returns nothing, has anyone encountered this issue? Many thanks.

Comment: Had you checked logs of docker container? `docker logs YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME`

Comment: what is the CMD of the image? What happens if you run a shell and then run the CMD manually?

Comment: You'll need to describe what you're running inside the container (include a Dockerfile and dependencies if possible), what you expect from the output, and why (was this tested outside of a container).

Comment: ```docker logs YOUR_CONTAINER_NAME``` returns nothing too.

Comment: CMD is to run a model and a Python script. I also have a bash script which contains the AWS crendential (so I wanted to run the container with AWS credential because there's a Python script inside the container to upload a file to S3), ```sh xxxxx.sh``` this command retunrs me nothing. And if I run ```docker run -it xxx``` returns me nothing as well. I don't know what I did wrong.

Comment: So you have a script that if you run it outputs nothing and exits, and when you put it in a container it outputs nothing and exits. Seems like an expected result. We can't debug without a [mcve].

Answer (score 2):

Did you do: `docker run -it xxxx`?
-i flag, connects your terminal to STDIN
-t flag, provides a better visualization of what you see on the screen
-it is a syntactic coating for -i -t flags used separately

Also, what does it show on doing `docker ps --all`? Does it show that the container is running?

Comment: When I run ```docker ps -a``` the status is ``` Exited (0) 16 hours ago```, does it mean the container is not running?

Comment: Ya, seems like the container stopped running.